# Having an issue installing flutter onto my windows 10 computer

Tags: git, android-studio, flutter, dart, path

So, I installed flutter onto my windows system exactly the way its shown on the site, but when I run flutter doctor in command prompt I receive an error:

```
C:\Users\12396>flutter doctor
'crumb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Error: unable to find git in your PATH
```

I have never seen an error like this before, and I've tried looking around and cant find any details on it. I have tried reinstalling flutter, android studio, and git, but neither one of those has fixed the issue. I have updated my environment variables for git and flutter. I went into my system bios and enabled virtualization.
If anyone has a solution it would be of great help.

Comment: With the error info can you try `git --version` on your command line and if git is not installed I think first step would be to add git and you can get it from git for windows your version. Check again with git --version before you run flutter doctor.

Comment: git version is 2.24.0.windows.2